# Permission for creating organization's site in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have defined a custom role and assigned it to UserX. I want UserX to create an Organization , then create the Organization's site. I have checked all the permissions under "Users and Organizations" section while defining custom role. However I am unable to create Organization's site.

When I check Create Site Box in the Organization Site section of Organization Information, I get

```
    Public Pages
    This organization does not have any public pages.

    Private Pages
    This organization does not have any private pages.
```

Where I am expecting it to give a selection box to select either Community Site, Intranet Site or any other custom site template.

Which permission shall I include to my custom role , to get that selection box to select either Community Site, Intranet Site or any other custom site template ?

Answer (score 2):

Goto Control Panel -> Sites. It shows the list of sites. Select if the site you want exists, if not create a site by clicking on the add site button. Then from the site list click on the Actions button and select Manage Pages option. Select Private Pages tab and choose Add Page button to add private page to this site.

Enjoy !!
~Bhuwan